# Laravel application has noticeable disparity in data loading times between the server environment and local development

Tags: linux, laravel, eloquent, linux-kernel

In my Laravel application, the below function has a noticeable disparity in data loading times between the server environment and local development.
The local development data loading time is 2.2 seconds, and the server environment data loading time is 21.59 seconds. Both environments have the same database. What is the reason for that?

```
public function getBookings()
{
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('customer')) {
        $bookings = Booking::where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customer->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    } else {
        $bookings = Booking::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    }
    return $bookings->map(function ($booking) {
        return $this->mapBookingData($booking);
    });
}
```